# In classic asp how can you wait for a response in the server side code?

Tags: asp-classic

I currently have a classic asp page.  It has some code that it processes.  I need to somehow call a url from the classic asp page, wait for the url response and continue the asp processesing.. is that even possible?

example classic asp page

-- processing server side code

-- call url.. wait for response...

-- then continue processing asp page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XML HTTP COM component on the server side, similarly to how you do in client-side AJAX calls in JavaScript.

Here's a tutorial using the component in Classic ASP:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210927184623/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110100-1.shtml